# Aumentar el ancho a los gráficos width - angular

Tags: css, angular, css3, flexbox

disculpen tengo un problemilla,
tengo dos graficos highchart que quiero mostrar la mitad y mitad, he notado que cuando coloco fxLayout y fxFlex , los graficos se reducen a pequeño y quisiera que abarquen todo el ancho

cuando doy clic en el cuadradito chiquito se minimiza y cuando le sigo dando se agranda como quiero

cuando doy clic varias clic al ultimo si se grafica todo el ancho

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intenado con este codigo pero nada, si me podrian ayudar por favor.

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap">
  <div fxFlex="50" fxFlex.gt-sm="50" fxFlex.sm="100">
    <mat-card class="default">
        <p class="text-blue ml-1 mt-1">Transacciones por Corresponsal</p>
      <mat-card-content > 
          <app-graphic-basic [config_graphic]='config_graphic_tcorr' class="grafica-full-fix"></app-graphic-basic> 
      </mat-card-content>
     
    </mat-card>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="50" fxFlex.gt-sm="50" fxFlex.sm="100" >
    <mat-card class="default">
        <p class="text-blue ml-1 mt-1">Transacciones por Territorio</p>
      <mat-card-content > 
      
            <app-graphic-basic [config_graphic]='config_graphic_tteri' class="grafica-full-fix"></app-graphic-basic>  
       
      </mat-card-content> 
      
    </mat-card>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

**Adjunto la imagen como se ve**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Quisiera que se vea asì**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**componente del graphic-basic.component
con respecto a css no tiene ninguno**

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap">
    <div 
        *ngFor='let item of carousel;'
        fxFlex="100" 
        fxFlex.gt-sm="20" 
        fxFlex.sm="50" 
        [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{scale:'.9',delay:'300ms'}}">
        <mat-card>
            <mat-card-title fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                <small class="text-muted">{{item.desc}}</small>
                <span fxFlex></span>
                <mat-chip class="icon-chip" [style.background-color]="item.avance.color" selected="true" *ngIf="item.avance.value">
                    <mat-icon>trending_up</mat-icon>{{item.avance.value | percent :'.0-0'}}
                </mat-chip>
            </mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-content>
                <h3 class="m-0 font-normal">{{item.value | localNumber :item.format}}</h3>
                <small class="text-muted">{{item.unit}}</small>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>


<div *ngIf="isLoadingGraphic">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" class="shop-top-toolbar">
        <span fxFlex></span>
        <div [fxHide.lt-md]="true">
            <button mat-icon-button [color]="grilla === 50 ? 'primary' : ''" (click)="red()">
                <mat-icon>apps</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
        <span fxFlex="20px"></span>
    </div>


    <div fxLayout="row wrap">
        <div fxFlex="100" [fxFlex.gt-sm]="grilla" *ngFor='let cg of config_graphic;let i=index'>
            <div class="m-033">
                <highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [(update)]="update[i]" [options]="co[i]" 
                    [runOutsideAngular]=true style="width: 100%; height: 400px;max-height: 80vh; display: block;">
                </highcharts-chart>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  
</div>
```

he encontrado que con esto se cambia el tamaño, coloco la clase pero no se renderiza, como si no lo esta leyendo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya intentaste esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586670/highchartss-width-is-not-able-to-fill-100-of-parent?

Comment: @junior amigo ayudame

Comment: Piero, ¿has revisado e intentado replicar el contenido de la respuesta del enlace que te ha dado el buen @junior ?

Comment: @fredyfx si pero igual nada , se grafica bien cuando le doy clic en esos cuadritos chiquitos pero yo quiero que por defecto muestre grande

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno la soluciòn que hice, es hacerle un seguimiento con Inspeccionar Elemento y ver que estilos se agregaban en cada direcctires de Angular.
Observaba que se agregaban estas clases dinamicas mismo de Higcharts por lo que le agregue :Host ::ng-deep y la clase para que funcione.

```
:host ::ng-deep  .ng-tns-c13-4 {
  flex-flow: row wrap; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;
}

:host ::ng-deep .ng-tns-c13-4 .ng-star-inserted{
  flex: 1 1 100%; box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 100%;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Creo que el problema es el ancho de pantalla, tienes configurado en el div

```
fxFlex.sm="50"
```

Eso provoca que el responsive fuerce a que ocupe la mitad del tamaño en las pantallas pequeñas-medianas, en tu ejemplo de código seria solo eliminar la parte que lo fuerza en el componente del graphic-basic.component

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap">
    <div 
        *ngFor='let item of carousel;'
        fxFlex="100" 
        [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{scale:'.9',delay:'300ms'}}">
        <mat-card>
            <mat-card-title fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                <small class="text-muted">{{item.desc}}</small>
                <span fxFlex></span>
                <mat-chip class="icon-chip" [style.background-color]="item.avance.color" selected="true" *ngIf="item.avance.value">
                    <mat-icon>trending_up</mat-icon>{{item.avance.value | percent :'.0-0'}}
                </mat-chip>
            </mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-content>
                <h3 class="m-0 font-normal">{{item.value | localNumber :item.format}}</h3>
                <small class="text-muted">{{item.unit}}</small>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>


<div *ngIf="isLoadingGraphic">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" class="shop-top-toolbar">
        <span fxFlex></span>
        <div [fxHide.lt-md]="true">
            <button mat-icon-button [color]="grilla === 50 ? 'primary' : ''" (click)="red()">
                <mat-icon>apps</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
        <span fxFlex="20px"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: podrias hacer un ejemplo

Comment: si le he quitado pero igual